# Spring Authorization Server 0.3.1 problem registering several RegisteredClientRepository

Tags: spring-security, spring-authorization-server

Hi,

I need register several clients but when I try to do this it this exception is thrown, I have made sure that each client has a different identifier:

*Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Registered client must be unique. Found duplicate client secret for identifier: appclientes
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.client.InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository.lambda$assertUniqueIdentifiers$0(InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository.java:107)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$ValuesView.forEach(ConcurrentHashMap.java:4772)
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.client.InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository.assertUniqueIdentifiers(InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository.java:95)
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.client.InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository.(InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository.java:64)
at com.pryconsa.backend.config.AuthorizationServerConfig.registeredClientRepository(AuthorizationServerConfig.java:100)
at com.pryconsa.backend.config.AuthorizationServerConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$46216dc1.CGLIB$registeredClientRepository$2()
at com.pryconsa.backend.config.AuthorizationServerConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$46216dc1$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$b448ca22.invoke()
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)
at com.pryconsa.backend.config.AuthorizationServerConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$46216dc1.registeredClientRepository()
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
... 58 common frames omitted
*

My code is the following:

```
@Bean
public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() {        
    TokenSettings tokenClient1Settings = TokenSettings.builder()
            .accessTokenTimeToLive(Duration.ofSeconds(client1AccessTokenValiditySeconds))
            .build();
    
    RegisteredClient registeredClient1 = RegisteredClient.withId(client1Id)
            .clientId(client1Id)
            .clientSecret("{noop}" + client1Secret)
            .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.PASSWORD)
            .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
            .tokenSettings(tokenBackofficeSettings)
            .scope("read")
            .scope("write")
            .build();
    
    TokenSettings tokenClient2Settings = TokenSettings.builder()
            .accessTokenTimeToLive(Duration.ofSeconds(client2AccessTokenValiditySeconds))
            .build();
    
    RegisteredClient registeredClient2 = RegisteredClient.withId(client2Id)
            .clientId(client2Id)
            .clientSecret("{noop}" + client2Secret)
            .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.PASSWORD)
            .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
            .tokenSettings(tokenClient2Settings)
            .scope("read")
            .scope("write")
            .build();
    
    return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(List.of(registeredClient1, registeredClient2));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the exception is realy helpful in this case. It literally tells you what is going wrong here.

- You already have registered client with that client-id in the DB
- Or your clientId1 and clientId2 have the same value